# Add a conditional variable in a data frame that takes into account the time intervals between rows for the same data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have the data frame `df1` that summarises for intervals of one hour the number of times that an animal has been seen in a place.

As an example:

```
df1<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-09-27 10:00:00","2016-09-27 10:00:00","2016-09-27 11:00:00","2016-09-27 11:00:00","2016-09-27 12:00:00","2016-09-27 12:00:00","2016-09-27 13:00:00","2016-09-27 13:00:00","2016-09-27 14:00:00","2016-09-27 14:00:00","2016-09-27 15:00:00","2016-09-27 15:00:00","2016-09-27 16:00:00","2016-09-27 16:00:00","2016-09-27 17:00:00","2016-09-27 17:00:00","2016-09-27 18:00:00","2016-09-27 18:00:00"),
                 AnimalID= c(8,9,8,9,8,9,8,9,8,9,8,9,8,9,8,9,8,9),
                 Times_seen=c(6,3,0,7,0,2,0,0,7,0,2,0,5,0,2,1,0,8))

> df1
              DateTime AnimalID Times_seen
1  2016-09-27 10:00:00        8          6
2  2016-09-27 10:00:00        9          3
3  2016-09-27 11:00:00        8          0
4  2016-09-27 11:00:00        9          7
5  2016-09-27 12:00:00        8          0
6  2016-09-27 12:00:00        9          2
7  2016-09-27 13:00:00        8          0
8  2016-09-27 13:00:00        9          0
9  2016-09-27 14:00:00        8          7
10 2016-09-27 14:00:00        9          0
11 2016-09-27 15:00:00        8          2
12 2016-09-27 15:00:00        9          0
13 2016-09-27 16:00:00        8          5
14 2016-09-27 16:00:00        9          0
15 2016-09-27 17:00:00        8          2
16 2016-09-27 17:00:00        9          1
17 2016-09-27 18:00:00        8          0
18 2016-09-27 18:00:00        9          8
```

According to this, I want to add a new variable in `df1` that says if the animal is likely to be or not there (if you don't see it doesn't mean it wasn't there). Obviously, if `Times_seen` is bigger than 0, we add `Yes` in the variable `df1$Presence`. But, when `Times_seen` is 0, I want to consider two options: A) The animal was there but no one saw it (and then, `Presence` is `Yes`), and B) The animal wasn't in this place (and then, `Presence` is `No`).

The criteria for considering that the animal wasn't anymore in the place is: The animal's `Times_seen` variable is 0 and it was not seen in this place IN THE PREVIOUS two hours.

As an example of what I would expect to get is:

```
> df1
              DateTime AnimalID Times_seen Presence
1  2016-09-27 10:00:00        8          6      Yes
2  2016-09-27 10:00:00        9          3      Yes
3  2016-09-27 11:00:00        8          0      Yes
4  2016-09-27 11:00:00        9          7      Yes
5  2016-09-27 12:00:00        8          0      Yes
6  2016-09-27 12:00:00        9          2      Yes
7  2016-09-27 13:00:00        8          0       No
8  2016-09-27 13:00:00        9          0      Yes
9  2016-09-27 14:00:00        8          7      Yes
10 2016-09-27 14:00:00        9          0      Yes
11 2016-09-27 15:00:00        8          2      Yes
12 2016-09-27 15:00:00        9          0       No
13 2016-09-27 16:00:00        8          5      Yes
14 2016-09-27 16:00:00        9          0       No
15 2016-09-27 17:00:00        8          2      Yes
16 2016-09-27 17:00:00        9          1      Yes
17 2016-09-27 18:00:00        8          0      Yes
18 2016-09-27 18:00:00        9          8      Yes
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is that 'Presence' column all correct because by checkingthe 7th row, it comes out 'Yes' for me. because if I check previous and next 2 hours, it woud be `0 0 0 7`

Comment: You're right akrun. The 7th row is `Yes` since at `14:00:00` (less than 2 hours) the same animal is detected. Sorry for the mistake. I've modified it. And I'm thinking it could be the same for row 5th, couldn't it? Because the condition of "0 observations" in the previous and the next 2 hours doesn't fit...

Comment: For some reason if I use the conditions, I get all TRUE `df1 %>% mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(DateTime)) %>% group_by(AnimalID) %>% mutate(Presence = map_lgl(DateTime,  ~  any(Times_seen[dplyr::between(DateTime, .x - hours(2), .x + hours(2))] > 0)))`

Comment: The only row where should appear `No` is in row 3, since it is the unique case in which there is two consecutive hours (in this case after) with `0 observations`. Could the ploblem be in the OR condition? I mean, does your code consider that either `the previous two hours` OR `the next two hours` is enought to consider as `No` in the `df1$Presence` variable? With ONLY ONE out of two conditions been satisfied is enough!!

Comment: Did you meant 2 hours prior or 2 rows before/after

Comment: I tried `df1 %>% group_by(AnimalID) %>% mutate(Presence = map_lgl(row_number(), ~ any(Times_seen[between(row_number(), pmin(1,.x - 2), pmin(.x + 2, n()))] > 0)))`, but that also gives all TRUE

Comment: You have a circular definition of the `presence` column. Do you suppose to process in chronological order ? If yes, you do not consider the previous two hours.

Comment: @akrun, Mmmm... well, the data frame mixes different individuals in consecutive rows so I guess it is better if we refer to hours. For instance, individual 8 is seen at 10:00:00 and at 14:00:00, but not at 11:00:00, 12:00:00 or 13:00:00. In this case, at 11:00:00 (row 3) and at 13:00:00 (row 7) we can say it wasn't present, since we have two nex hours without observations (rows 5 and 7 with regard row 3) and two previous hours without observations (rows 3 and 5 with regard 7) respectively. Do I explain myself?

Comment: @akrun, correcting myself... in `df1$Presence[7]` should appear `No` according with my logic... As I said in my previous comment, there are two previous hours (rows 3 and 5) without observations of this individual...

Comment: @AlexandreB., I guess the option you comment could be useful as well... But I prefer to consider only the PREVIOUS TWO HOURS for my reasons... If in the previous two hours there are no observations either, then consider it is not present. I modified the post to consider this criterion instead of "previous OR next" criteria.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreB. for your comments. Well, in my real data I will modify this period, instead of 2 hours will be 24 hours... and in my case is a fish. I can't explain you here but I am pretty sure that if I don't see an animal in consecutive 24 hours it is because it moves somewhere else :). What I would like is to create a variable in which I consider the previous hours to say if the animal is likely to be already or not...

Comment: @Dekike Yes I agree with you.

Comment: @akrun, as Alexandre B. recommended me, I've modified the criteria and instead of beeing two hours either before of after, I think it is better to consider ONLY THE TWO HOURS BEFORE... In this situation, in the example, only row 7 should have a `No` in the variable `Presence`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As akrun indicated in one of his comments, this is the code I found useful:

```
df1<- df1 %>% mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(DateTime)) %>% 
  group_by(AnimalID) %>% 
  mutate(Presence = map_lgl(DateTime, ~ any(Times_seen[dplyr::between(DateTime, .x - hours(2), .x + hours(0))] > 0)))

> df1
# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   AnimalID [2]
   DateTime            AnimalID Times_seen Presence
   <dttm>                 <dbl>      <dbl> <lgl>   
 1 2016-09-27 10:00:00        8          6 TRUE    
 2 2016-09-27 10:00:00        9          3 TRUE    
 3 2016-09-27 11:00:00        8          0 TRUE    
 4 2016-09-27 11:00:00        9          7 TRUE    
 5 2016-09-27 12:00:00        8          0 TRUE    
 6 2016-09-27 12:00:00        9          2 TRUE    
 7 2016-09-27 13:00:00        8          0 FALSE   
 8 2016-09-27 13:00:00        9          0 TRUE    
 9 2016-09-27 14:00:00        8          7 TRUE    
10 2016-09-27 14:00:00        9          0 TRUE    
11 2016-09-27 15:00:00        8          2 TRUE    
12 2016-09-27 15:00:00        9          0 FALSE   
13 2016-09-27 16:00:00        8          5 TRUE    
14 2016-09-27 16:00:00        9          0 FALSE   
15 2016-09-27 17:00:00        8          2 TRUE    
16 2016-09-27 17:00:00        9          1 TRUE    
17 2016-09-27 18:00:00        8          0 TRUE    
18 2016-09-27 18:00:00        9          8 TRUE
```

Note: the code allows you to indicate the number of hours you want to consider before and after for saying `No` in `df1$Presence`.